# AttributeError: module 'htmlmin.middleware' has no attribute 'MarkRequestMiddleware'

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, heroku

Trying to deploy my Django Application in Heroku Platform including htmlmin and gzip the application crashed with H10 error code. Inspecting log looks like that the error is related to

`AttributeError: module 'htmlmin.middleware' has no attribute 'MarkRequestMiddleware'`

**Running locally works perfect** (I don´t know why), but after deployment in Heroku Platform the Application doesn´t work.

Here is the **settings.py** code:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
    'django.middleware.gzip.GZipMiddleware',
    "htmlmin.middleware.HtmlMinifyMiddleware",
    "htmlmin.middleware.MarkRequestMiddleware",
    "whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware",  
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware",    
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",    
    "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware", 

]

...

HTML_MINIFY = True
```

Here is my **requirements.txt** file:

```
django
django_compressor
htmlmin
gunicorn
django-heroku
pip==21.0.1
numpy==1.19.1
wordcloud==1.8.1
requests==2.24.0
urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1
matplotlib==3.3.4
wikipedia-API==0.5.3
livereload>=2.6.1
whitenoise>=5.0
```

Here is the Tail Log in Heroku App.

```
2021-09-02T18:56:35.730191+00:00 app[web.1]: mod = importlib.import_module(module)
2021-09-02T18:56:35.730191+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
2021-09-02T18:56:35.730192+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2021-09-02T18:56:35.730192+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
2021-09-02T18:56:35.730193+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
2021-09-02T18:56:35.730193+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked        
2021-09-02T18:56:35.730193+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
2021-09-02T18:56:35.730194+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
2021-09-02T18:56:35.730194+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed      
2021-09-02T18:56:35.730194+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/biblestatistic/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
2021-09-02T18:56:35.730194+00:00 app[web.1]: application = get_wsgi_application()
2021-09-02T18:56:35.730195+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 13, in get_wsgi_application
2021-09-02T18:56:35.730195+00:00 app[web.1]: return WSGIHandler()
2021-09-02T18:56:35.730195+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 127, in __init__
2021-09-02T18:56:35.730195+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_middleware()
2021-09-02T18:56:35.730196+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 40, in load_middleware
2021-09-02T18:56:35.730196+00:00 app[web.1]: middleware = import_string(middleware_path)
2021-09-02T18:56:35.730196+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 22, in import_string
2021-09-02T18:56:35.730197+00:00 app[web.1]: raise ImportError('Module "%s" does not define a "%s" attribute/class' % (        
2021-09-02T18:56:35.730197+00:00 app[web.1]: ImportError: Module "htmlmin.middleware" does not define a "MarkRequestMiddleware" attribute/class
2021-09-02T18:56:35.730648+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-09-02 18:56:35 +0000] [7] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 7)
2021-09-02T18:56:35.940547+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-09-02 18:56:35 +0000] [8] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2021-09-02T18:56:35.940551+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-09-02T18:56:35.940552+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 20, in import_string
2021-09-02T18:56:35.940552+00:00 app[web.1]: return getattr(module, class_name)
2021-09-02T18:56:35.940553+00:00 app[web.1]: AttributeError: module 'htmlmin.middleware' has no attribute 'MarkRequestMiddleware'
2021-09-02T18:56:35.940553+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-09-02T18:56:35.940553+00:00 app[web.1]: The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
2021-09-02T18:56:35.940554+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-09-02T18:56:35.940554+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-09-02T18:56:35.940554+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 589, in spawn_worker
2021-09-02T18:56:35.940555+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2021-09-02T18:56:35.940555+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 134, in init_process
2021-09-02T18:56:35.940556+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2021-09-02T18:56:35.940556+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi
2021-09-02T18:56:35.940556+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2021-09-02T18:56:35.940557+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 
67, in wsgi
2021-09-02T18:56:35.940557+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2021-09-02T18:56:35.940557+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load
2021-09-02T18:56:35.940558+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2021-09-02T18:56:35.940558+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp
2021-09-02T18:56:35.940558+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2021-09-02T18:56:35.940559+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 359, in import_app
2021-09-02T18:56:35.940559+00:00 app[web.1]: mod = importlib.import_module(module)
2021-09-02T18:56:35.940560+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
2021-09-02T18:56:35.940560+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2021-09-02T18:56:35.940560+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
2021-09-02T18:56:35.940561+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
2021-09-02T18:56:35.940561+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked        
2021-09-02T18:56:35.940561+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
2021-09-02T18:56:35.940562+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
2021-09-02T18:56:35.940562+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed      
2021-09-02T18:56:35.940562+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/biblestatistic/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
2021-09-02T18:56:35.940562+00:00 app[web.1]: application = get_wsgi_application()
2021-09-02T18:56:35.940563+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 13, in get_wsgi_application
2021-09-02T18:56:35.940563+00:00 app[web.1]: return WSGIHandler()
2021-09-02T18:56:35.940563+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 127, in __init__
2021-09-02T18:56:35.940563+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_middleware()
2021-09-02T18:56:35.940564+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 40, in load_middleware
2021-09-02T18:56:35.940564+00:00 app[web.1]: middleware = import_string(middleware_path)
2021-09-02T18:56:35.940564+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 22, in import_string
2021-09-02T18:56:35.940565+00:00 app[web.1]: raise ImportError('Module "%s" does not define a "%s" attribute/class' % (        
2021-09-02T18:56:35.940565+00:00 app[web.1]: ImportError: Module "htmlmin.middleware" does not define a "MarkRequestMiddleware" attribute/class
2021-09-02T18:56:35.940826+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-09-02 18:56:35 +0000] [8] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 8)
2021-09-02T18:56:36.110011+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-09-02T18:56:36.110030+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 209, in run
2021-09-02T18:56:36.110342+00:00 app[web.1]: self.sleep()
2021-09-02T18:56:36.110354+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 357, in sleep
2021-09-02T18:56:36.110545+00:00 app[web.1]: ready = select.select([self.PIPE[0]], [], [], 1.0)
2021-09-02T18:56:36.110555+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 242, in handle_chld
2021-09-02T18:56:36.113107+00:00 app[web.1]: self.reap_workers()
2021-09-02T18:56:36.113121+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 525, in reap_workers
2021-09-02T18:56:36.113423+00:00 app[web.1]: raise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)
2021-09-02T18:56:36.113475+00:00 app[web.1]: gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>
2021-09-02T18:56:36.113485+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-09-02T18:56:36.113486+00:00 app[web.1]: During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
2021-09-02T18:56:36.113486+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-09-02T18:56:36.113488+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-09-02T18:56:36.113502+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/bin/gunicorn", line 8, in <module>
2021-09-02T18:56:36.113595+00:00 app[web.1]: sys.exit(run())
2021-09-02T18:56:36.113609+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 67, in run
2021-09-02T18:56:36.113695+00:00 app[web.1]: WSGIApplication("%(prog)s [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]").run()
2021-09-02T18:56:36.113704+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 
231, in run
2021-09-02T18:56:36.113838+00:00 app[web.1]: super().run()
2021-09-02T18:56:36.113848+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 
72, in run
2021-09-02T18:56:36.113938+00:00 app[web.1]: Arbiter(self).run()
2021-09-02T18:56:36.113948+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 229, in run
2021-09-02T18:56:36.114078+00:00 app[web.1]: self.halt(reason=inst.reason, exit_status=inst.exit_status)
2021-09-02T18:56:36.114093+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 342, in halt
2021-09-02T18:56:36.114250+00:00 app[web.1]: self.stop()
2021-09-02T18:56:36.114263+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 393, in stop
2021-09-02T18:56:36.114415+00:00 app[web.1]: time.sleep(0.1)
2021-09-02T18:56:36.114426+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 242, in handle_chld
2021-09-02T18:56:36.114545+00:00 app[web.1]: self.reap_workers()
2021-09-02T18:56:36.114554+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 525, in reap_workers
2021-09-02T18:56:36.114751+00:00 app[web.1]: raise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)
2021-09-02T18:56:36.114787+00:00 app[web.1]: gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>
2021-09-02T18:56:36.202731+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-09-02T18:56:36.281947+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-09-02T18:58:20.408763+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=biblestatistic-test.herokuapp.com request_id=54789e04-96e4-4cd6-b4e2-b4d900ece656 fwd="177.221.50.1" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Here is the Build log

```
-----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
-----> Using buildpack: heroku/python
-----> Python app detected
-----> Using Python version specified in runtime.txt
 !     Python has released a security update! Please consider upgrading to python-3.9.7
       Learn More: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes
-----> No change in requirements detected, installing from cache
-----> Using cached install of python-3.9.6
-----> Installing pip 20.2.4, setuptools 47.1.1 and wheel 0.36.2
-----> Installing SQLite3
-----> Installing requirements with pip
       Collecting pip==21.0.1
         Downloading pip-21.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (1.5 MB)
       Installing collected packages: pip
         Attempting uninstall: pip
           Found existing installation: pip 20.2.4
           Uninstalling pip-20.2.4:
             Successfully uninstalled pip-20.2.4
       Successfully installed pip-21.0.1
-----> $ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
       Found another file with the destination path 'lang-logo.png'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
       Found another file with the destination path 'images/favicon-16x16.png'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
       Found another file with the destination path 'images/bs_blue.png'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
       Found another file with the destination path 'images/cloud-header.png'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
       Found another file with the destination path 'images/bs-logo.png'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
       Found another file with the destination path 'images/en.svg'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
       Found another file with the destination path 'images/es.svg'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
       Found another file with the destination path 'images/arrow-right-transparent-smaller.png'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
       Found another file with the destination path 'images/favicon.ico'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
       Found another file with the destination path 'images/404.svg'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
       Found another file with the destination path 'images/favicon-32x32.png'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
       Found another file with the destination path 'images/pt-br.svg'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
       Found another file with the destination path 'images/prj/bs_blue.png'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
       Found another file with the destination path 'images/prj/bs_blue.xcf'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
       Found another file with the destination path 'js/bootstrap-modal-ios.js'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
       Found another file with the destination path 'js/bundle.js'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
       Found another file with the destination path 'css/theme.css'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
       Found another file with the destination path 'css/styles.css'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
       Found another file with the destination path 'css/default.css'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
       Found another file with the destination path 'css/theme.min.css'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
       Found another file with the destination path 'css/styles.min.css'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
       Found another file with the destination path 'css/default.min.css'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
       150 static files copied to '/tmp/build_ba093552/staticfiles', 466 post-processed.
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types -> web
-----> Compressing...
       Done: 235.2M
-----> Launching...
       Released v20
       https://myapp.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

Any suggestion about how to fix this error?

Thanks,

Comment: What version of `htmlmin` do you use here?

Comment: Hello @WillemVanOnsem locally **htmlmin-0.1.12**

Answer (score 0):

I WOULD SUGGEST ALWAYS TRY TO USE OTHER MIDDLEWARES AFTER THE `"django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",` as sometimes the session data loads with a fresh start and other middleware don't work perfectly.

try like this>>>

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
     "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware",  
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware",    
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",    
    "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
    'django.middleware.gzip.GZipMiddleware',
    "htmlmin.middleware.HtmlMinifyMiddleware",
    "htmlmin.middleware.MarkRequestMiddleware",
    "whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware", 

]
```

It may work. If no it's always a best practice.

Comment: Hello Fatin Ishrak Rafi, unfortunetly the error persist. The problem is after deployment in Heroku Platform

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution that I have found.

1. Change the **requirements.txt** dependencies from `htmlmin` to `django-htmlmin`.
2. Include in **settings.py** `from htmlmin.minify import html_minify` as the reference. The reason for that is based in the file [middleware.py](https://github.com/cobrateam/django-htmlmin/blob/master/htmlmin/middleware.py) from the original library just to garantee the relation between `HtmlMinifyMiddleware` class and  `MarkRequestMiddleware`

When deployed in Heroku works perfectly.